# How to implement custom navigation handling with pretty faces - unable to pass in required params

Tags: jsf, navigation, prettyfaces

using PF 3.3.1, PrettyFaces 3.3.3 and JSF/Mojarra2.1.

I have a custom navigation handler to handle "cancel" button on my application pages - the cancel button needs to return to the previous (referring) page.  I have implemented a stack-based solution that holds the trail of the user's navigation and almost finished implementing the navigationHandler - but now I've hit a snag.  I can't seem to get the cancel action to navigate back to the page I want.  I've tried the following:

`FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().redirect` within my NavigationHandler.handleNavigation.

So next I tried something like (again, in the NavigationHandler.handleNavigation):

```
BreadCrumbStack.NavDetail navDetail = breadCrumbStack.popLastCrumb(facesContext);
if (navDetail != null) {
    navDetail.getPrevViewId() + " ActionMethod: " + navDetail.getActionMethod() + " ActionName:    " + navDetail.getActionName());
    facesContext.getViewRoot().setViewId(navDetail.getPrevViewId());
    parentHandler.handleNavigation(fc, navDetail.getActionMethod(), navDetail.getActionName());
    return;                     
}
```

Now the problem is that the URLMapping (pretty faces 3.3.2) - is complaining that there is no ID, which is required:

`PrettyException: Exception occurred while building URL for Mapping  Id Required value was null`

I have the full URL with ID at the end of it - which I wanted to use in my redirect - however, it seems that the redirect isn't working correctly from within my custom navigationHandler's handleNavigation method.

Does anyone have any ideas about how I might be able to elegantly solve this problem?  the IDs/params tacked onto the end of the url can vary for each screen, and I don't particularly want to hack a solution together - it would be nice if somehow I could just give the url to some predefined class in PrettyFaces and it would work OR do a complete redirect (which I couldn't get to work)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Anybody...?  Got ideas about why redirect doesn't work inside a custom navigationHandler?

Comment: JSF's implicit navigation allows you to navigate from one page into another just returning the navigation case you want in the action method. It also works with file paths. I.e. if you do return /navigation/user.xhtml?name=admin and you have it mapped properly into your *pretty-config.xml* file, you can reach the parameter from the destination managed bean.